# Download file to location that requires permission

Tags: node.js, download

I'm creating a system to be used inside my company.
This system will create an email signature for the user.

After I have created the signature.html, I want to download it to the user's AppData folder.

```
var downloadPath = 'C:\\Users\\' + login + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Signatures'
download(htmlData, downloadPath, displayInstructions)

function download(url, dest, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(url);
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close(cb);
        });
    });
}
```

However, when I try to do this, I get an "Unhandled error event" in console, and Chrome Debugger says `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` I assume that this is because the AppData folder is restricted, is there a way I can pass administrative permissions with this function?
I've only been programming for a few months, so feedback is welcome!

All of the code:

```
// Various variable declaraitons...
//

app.get('/signature/createsig/result/:login/:name/:job/:DDI/:mobile', function(req, res) {
    var htmlData = fs.readFileSync('signature/Signature.htm', 'utf-8');
    var login = req.params.login
    var name = req.params.name
    var job = req.params.job
    var DDI = req.params.DDI
    var mobile = req.params.mobile
    var downloadPath = 'C:\\Users\\' + login + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Signatures';
    htmlData = htmlData.replace(/%%%name%%%/g, name)
    htmlData = htmlData.replace(/%%%job%%%/g, job)
    htmlData = htmlData.replace(/%%%DDI%%%/g, DDI)
    htmlData = htmlData.replace(/%%%mobile%%%/g, mobile)
    download(htmlData, downloadPath, displayInstructions)

    function download(url, dest, cb) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(url);
        var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function() {
                file.close(cb);
            });
        });
    }

    function displayInstructions() {
        // Display instructions
    }
})
```